# Translate whole column in Excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got a large table in Excel, and how can I translate two of the columns (from Chinese and Korean, respectively) to English, instead of using GOOGLETRANSLATE in Google sheet?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel? As you mention in your own question Google Sheets has the built-in [`GOOGLETRANSLATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en) function that does exactly what you are looking for, so I understand you are using Microsoft Excel, right?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFERROR({BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(x, GOOGLETRANSLATE(x, "zh", "en"))), 
          BYROW(B2:B, LAMBDA(y, GOOGLETRANSLATE(y, "ko", "en")))})
```

[image]